# how to achieve global Logout for specific SP from IDP side?

Tags: java, spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I have integrated Spring Saml with my application and it's working fine. I am able to login using SP-initiated SSO and IDP-initiated SSO. Also I added local logout settings as well. But I got one more requirement where user will login using SP-initiated SSO. After successful authentication, user will go to IDP selection page (ADFS 2.0 in my case) and select one SP and click on logout from this site.

At that time I need to trigger a session termination for client browser where my SP home page is open. Other SP should not be affected for this user.

There are many question related to single logout but my scenario is bit different. I want to logout from my application from global IDP page. Though I am able to logout locally and session is getting terminated. I have configured all setting given in this [Spring-Saml](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-sso.html#configuration-logout) doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a lot of doubt about SingleSignOut. But I believe that what you want is not the standard Single Logout Profile (paragraph 4.4). And ADFS certainly will not initiate the signout through the backchannel (SOAP Binding for paragraph 4.4.3.3.).

Maybe you can do the "illegal?" LogoutRequest (because all SPs should be singned out) with Redirect or Post binding from the IdP (ADFS). But maybe (I doubt and did not verify on the current patch levels) only in ADFS 2.0 on S2008R2 and S2012. On S2012R2 there is no chance at all. It is a dead-end street.

I guess Signout from one app really has no meaning. It is SSO! You could clear the local SP login session cookies and try using ForceAuthn on the AuthnRequest from the SP to the IdP. Would that produce the required effect? At least that is standard.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am also under same impression that one should logout from all SPs in case of SSO. So in that case how to proceed with singleLogout for all SPs.

Comment: The SP should send a LogoutRequest. The Issuers will do the rest.

Comment: But in my case IDP will send logout request then all SPs or one SP session should be terminatate.

Comment: As I said, better not go this path. But if I were to experiment with it, then I would take a look at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.UI.IdentityProviderInitiatedSignonPage.SingleLogout(). The IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx page derives from the proper class to call it.